# Kotlin Mutiplarform throws NPE with AVAudioRecorder

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm testing Kotlin Multiplatform to create an app PoC to record audio from Android/iOS. I've a common interface to encapsulate the native logic and for iOS I'm writting this code to create the recorder:

```
val settings = mapOf(
    "AVFormatIDKey" to kAudioFormatAppleIMA4,
    "AVSampleRateKey" to 44100.0,
    "AVNumberOfChannelsKey" to 2,
    "AVEncoderBitRateKey" to 12800,
    "AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey" to 16,
    "AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey" to false,
    "AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey" to false,
) as Map<Any?, *>
val url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath = outputFile)
// Check values used
println(settings)
println("File is: ($url)")
memScoped {
    try {
        val error: ObjCObjectVar<NSError?> = alloc()
        recorder = AVAudioRecorder(url, settings, error.ptr)
        recorder?.meteringEnabled = true
        recorder?.prepareToRecord()
        println(error)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        println(e.toString())
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

Settings and URL used:

```
{AVFormatIDKey=1768775988, AVSampleRateKey=44100.0, AVNumberOfChannelsKey=2, AVEncoderBitRateKey=12800, AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey=16, AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey=false, AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey=false}
File is: (file:/Users/gazer/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/33505695-6067-4B93-81D3-087DF397396F/data/Containers/Data/Application/A931840F-93B9-4936-AFBD-BD834BD80AF5/Documents/recording.m4a -- file:///)
```

outoutFile string is created in the native part:

```
let audioFilename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("recording.m4a")

// outputFile == audioFilename.absoluteString

func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}
```

The problem is that I always get a NPE in the call to the constructor for `AVAudioRecorder` that is part of the AVFoundation of iOS.

```
at 2   shared                              0x10b760779        kfun:kotlin.RuntimeException#<init>(){} + 73 (/opt/buildAgent/work/acafc8c59a79cc1/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/Exceptions.kt:32:28)
at 3   shared                              0x10b7609b9        kfun:kotlin.NullPointerException#<init>(){} + 73 (/opt/buildAgent/work/acafc8c59a79cc1/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/Exceptions.kt:43:28)
at 4   shared                              0x10b7862d4        ThrowNullPointerException + 132 (/opt/buildAgent/work/acafc8c59a79cc1/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/native/internal/RuntimeUtils.kt:15:11)
at 5   shared                              0x10b6d3aae        kfun:ar.com.p39.powernotes.recorder.IOSAudioRecordThread#startRecording(){} + 2910
```

But if I wrote the iOS native part in swift and pass the instance from iOS code to kotlin, I've no problem calling this:

```
let settings: [String: Any] = [
    AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
    AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
]
var url = URL(string: outputFile)
do {
    recorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: url!, settings: settings)
    recorder?.isMeteringEnabled = true
    recorder?.prepareToRecord()
    recorder?.record()
catch {
    debugPrint("ERror")
}
```

This works as expected and I can record audio.

Any ideas how to debug why the kotlin bridge to Obj-c crash? Thanks

---

EDIT: SOLUTION

Looks like the problem was the settings map. I've changed to PCM and now it do not crash:

```
val settings = mapOf(
    "AVFormatIDKey" to kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
    "AVSampleRateKey" to 1600.0,
    "AVNumberOfChannelsKey" to 1,
    "AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey" to 8,
    "AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey" to false,
    "AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey" to false,
)
```

Comment: I'd started with checking `settings`/`url` values, other code seams fine

Comment: Thanks @PhilDukhov. I've added a println just before the memScoped and I will added the output to the original question.

Comment: I was able to read the error returned by AVAudioRecorder constructor: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1718449215.), looks like it's something related with the format in the settings.